# GWT Exception getLocalizedMessage()

Tags: gwt

Anyone now what message it will return, most of the time i am seeing empty or null. what type of implementation GWT have given for this.

I trying to use to log UI side error to log.

Comment: Are you talking about `java.lang.Exception.getLocalizedMessage()` ?

Comment: Yes in catch block e.getLocalizedMessage()

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the JavaDoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29)  and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getLocalizedMessage%28%29). As you can read the semantics for the latter are:

```
Creates a localized description of this throwable. Subclasses may override 
this method in order to produce a locale-specific message. For subclasses
that do not override this method, the default implementation returns the 
same result as getMessage()
```

Basically that means that you will have to take a look at the specific exception to determine what the localized message may be or mean, and also that if you're getting nothing, either the `.getMessage()` should also return nothing or the localized version is indeed overridden (or the implementation doesn't follow the contract, which is also very likely)...

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Hello charankumar Even I don't get anything from `exception.getLocalizedMessage()`.

So I use `exception.toString()` instead of that. It will give you type of the `Exception` (such as `NullPointerException`, `ClassCastException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException` etc.).

In addition if there is some string as localizedMessage, it will return you that also.

Comment: how about exception.getMessage() is it helps?

Comment: yes my thanks for your quick response and i to got some idea, because i am also try with different options available to me